# bs4 filtering with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to write a script that checks the steam store, and i'm having a problem with filtering out all of the listings that don't have a discount within their code. i want to keep only the listings with the span tag and the `<span>-percentage</span>` within them, and not the one without. here's my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from datetime import date
import requests as rq

inp = str(input('what would you like to search up?'))
w = ('https://store.steampowered.com/search/?term=' + inp)
page = rq.get(w)
soup = bsoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup.prettify()
sales = soup.find_all('div', class_="responsive_search_name_combined")

for sale in sales:
    p = soup.find('div', class_="col search_price responsive_secondrow")
    d = soup.find_all('div', class_="col search_discount responsive_secondrow")
    n = soup.find('span', class_="title")

    if None in (d, n, p):
        continue
    print(d)
```

and the output (containing the things i want to filter out/the things i want to keep)

```
<span>-16%</span>
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
<span>-19%</span>
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
```

etc etc.
i've tried replacing `d = soup.find_all('div', class_="col search_discount responsive_secondrow")` with `d = soup.find_all('span', string="-16%")` to see if that would work and it didnt.
i want to keep the span tags but not the div tags
could anyone help with this?

Comment: what is your output? what's the problem?

Comment: it's not really that it doesn't work, it's that when i run this with print(d) on the end i 
get something like
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
<span>-80%</span>
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
</div>, <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">

and i want to filter the results so it only shows the span tag within this div

Comment: i've tried using other variables to be more specific, or trying to access the span tag directly and that didn't work. i may have done it wrong, but i'm not sure what to do even after searching it up a ton

Comment: voted to close because it is not clear what output you expect and what output you are getting now.

Comment: it's not a code error, but that i don't know how to implement something and the research i've done hasn't helped me so far. i want to filter all of the div tags that don't contain a span tag with a percentage out so i'm left with only a percentage.

Comment: You are expected to create an exact input, and a corresponding exact output, manually or not, so that answers can copy-paste them and check themselves before posting. Please do so, so that we can help you.

Comment: @Sushil's answer seems fine by what you wrote, and yet you don't accept it. This is because you did not provide an output example.

Comment: i've provided more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a `try-except` block to the last `for` loop to solve your problem. Here is the full code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from datetime import date
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
inp = str(input('what would you like to search up?'))
w = ('https://store.steampowered.com/search/?term=' + inp)
page = rq.get(w)
soup = bsoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup.prettify()
sales = soup.find_all('div', class_="responsive_search_name_combined")

final = []

for sale in sales:
    p = soup.find('div', class_="col search_price responsive_secondrow")
    d = soup.find_all('div', class_="col search_discount responsive_secondrow")
    n = soup.find('span', class_="title")

    try:
        for element in d:
            span = element.span
            if span:
                final.append(span.text)
    except:
        pass
print(final)
```

Output:

```
what would you like to search up?>? among us
['-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%', '-10%', '-25%']
```

Comment: i've just tried that, but i still seem to be recieving a lot of empty div tags with no span containing the percentage. i think it may be because i'm doing soup.find_all,but i'm not sure

Comment: maybe i could use soup.find instead of soup.find_all and make it skip to the next listing if one doesn't have the span tag containing the percentage, but i'm not sure how i'd do that

Comment: that seems strange. i still get a lot of empty tags printed into my console

Comment: i think it could be that d is finding all of these tags, (because i used soup.find_all) and then when it appends once it finds a span tag it also appends all of the empty tags within it.

Comment: Oh...BTW, do you just wanna append the span tag to the final list?

Comment: yeah, i don't want the div tags. see the comments above and the post itself, because i've edited it to provide more info for u